# Getting error while importing panda in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting the error while importing panda

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kj/PycharmProjects/kj/parsing.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "H:\Python\New\lib\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "H:\Python\New\lib\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 421, in <module>
    if LooseVersion(dateutil.__version__) < LooseVersion('2.5'):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\version.py", line 52, in __lt__
    c = self._cmp(other)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\version.py", line 337, in _cmp
    if self.version < other.version:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel(open('Test.csv','rb'), sheetname='Sheet 1')
grouped = df.groupby('Date (IT)')
```

Comment: This is a very weird error. Have you changed any of the Pandas core files? If not I would recommend a fresh install

Comment: Is there any panda package in github with all dependencies because i am not allowed to connect other websites. i will be able to download from github and place it in python path

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `Date (IT)` column has mixed values (string and integers, dates, or missing values). So when pandas try to compare each value it fails because of different types. Please take a look at the column data and make sure all data is in a valid format.

Comment: It looks like the error is stemming from the `import pandas` statement, right? Assuming the traceback is copied as is and not missing information. So the issue is in Pandas, not in OP's data

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PyCharm installed at the moment but in the command line you can try to run:

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

followed by a reinstall : `pip install pandas`

Or you can always try to run it from PyCharm. It will automatically suggest to install the missing package.